# Convert a char array into hex (unsigned int) array

Tags: c, arrays, macos

I have an array that contains, for example, `AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF`. I have parsed it down to an array of chars of size 12 where every index now contains each of these digits.

I have to transform this parsed array into an array of unsigned int to use it for an ARP header.

In other words, the input was `AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF`, I broke it down into `parsed_mac = {A, A, B, B, C, C, D, D, E, E, F, F}` and I need to used this `parsed_mac` array to generate a `tgt_mac` array that looks like `tgt_mac = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF}`.

As of now, my `tgt_mac` is of type char. I will change it to unsigned int as soon as I understand how to properly process the data.

```
void parse_tgt_mac(char unformatted_mac[], char **tgt_mac)
{
    char parsed_mac[12] = {0};
    char* token;
    char* delimiter = ":";
    int i = 1;

    printf("parse_tgt_mac: %s\n", unformatted_mac);
    token = strtok(unformatted_mac, delimiter);
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        printf("%s\n", token);
        strcat(parsed_mac, token);
        printf("formatted_mac[]: %s\n", parsed_mac);
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);        
        i++;
        if(i > 11)
            break;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        printf("parsed_mac[%d]: %c\n", i, parsed_mac[i]);
    }
    *tgt_mac = parsed_mac;
    printf("tgt_mac: %s\n", *tgt_mac);
}
```

Using `unformatted_mac[]`'s input as AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF provides the following output:

```
parse_tgt_mac: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
formatted_mac[]: AA
formatted_mac[]: AABB
formatted_mac[]: AABBCC
formatted_mac[]: AABBCCDD
formatted_mac[]: AABBCCDDEE
formatted_mac[]: AABBCCDDEEFF
parsed_mac[0]: A
parsed_mac[1]: A
parsed_mac[2]: B
parsed_mac[3]: B
parsed_mac[4]: C
parsed_mac[5]: C
parsed_mac[6]: D
parsed_mac[7]: D
parsed_mac[8]: E
parsed_mac[9]: E
parsed_mac[10]: F
parsed_mac[11]: F
tgt_mac: AABBCCDDEEFF
```

ps. I am aware that in some versions, `strtok` is deprecated

Comment: Did I get old already and `strtok()` got deprecated? :P

Comment: Afaik it is now recommended to use strsep

Comment: 1) `char parsed_mac[12] = {0};` : `12` --> `13` 2) `*tgt_mac = parsed_mac;` : `parsed_mac` invalid outside the scope of this function.

Comment: I don't need to use `parsed_mac` outside of this scope as I am going to use `target_mac` for what I need. Also `12 -> 13`, you mean I need to increase the size because of `\0`? If so, I am quite sure I do not need that. It is documented somewhere that initialized arrays may have a `NUL` terminator rather than `\0`

Comment: http://ideone.com/5yI7K2